# Error JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly when runnin wso2server.sh as a service

Tags: environment-variables, centos7, wso2-api-manager, wso2

I've deployed WSO2 APIM on Centos 7. The Carbon starts fine until it's installed as a service.
WSO2 manual instructs only for Ubuntu-like os https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service

On centos I've created service file:

```
[Unit]

Description=WSO2 API Manager Server daemon
After=network.target

    [Service]
    Type=forking
    PIDFile=<API-M_HOME>/wso2carbon.pid
    ExecStart=<API-M_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh start
    ExecReload=<API-M_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh restart
    ExecStop=<API-M_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh stop

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I've set variable in /etc/profile:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-1.el7_6.x86_64/jre
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

echo $JAVA_HOME returns correct path with subdirs bin and lib and I can start WSO2APIM with simple

```
sh wso2server.sh
```

So, that again validates that the pats is set correct.
running:

```
systemctl start wso2apimanager.service
```

returns:

```
Feb 05 17:10:57 gwkm1 systemd[1]: Starting WSO2 API Manager Server daemon...
Feb 05 17:10:57 gwkm1 wso2server.sh[5265]: Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
Feb 05 17:10:57 gwkm1 wso2server.sh[5265]: CARBON cannot execute java
```

I'm out of ideas, what about you?

Comment: I want to mention, that I can start the service with command if I add the export JAVA_HOME... path directlu at the top of wso2server.sh file, but that is not an option..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service, modify you ExecStart like this :

`ExecStart=/bin/bash -c 'JAVA_HOME=/YOURJAVAPATH sh <API-M_HOME>/bin/wso2server.sh start'`

same for your ExecRestart.

Comment: Yep, thanks, this worked, but still looks more to me as a workaround. Anyway, better than modifying the .sh itself